# When installing the notepad++ snap, /mnt/* is not reachable

Tags: mount, wine, snap

I've installed notepad++ using `snap install notepad-plus-plus`, and its working great. The only issue I have is, when I go to /mnt/* (or Z:/mnt/ to be correct, since it's running in wine), non of my networkshares are there. Its just an empty folder.

Even when I open a file on a mount with thunar, n++ just tells me there is no file there.

Any way to make /mnt accessible?

Answer (score 2):

Currently `/mnt` is not supported by snapd but I will work on making that possible.

Please see this snapcraft forum thread for more details: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/mnt-mounts-should-be-supported/4669/5